# Excel VBA Select Option from Website Dropdown List while filling webform

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to automate this website using VBA excel. I am struck at a point where I have to select value from the dropdown box. I am very much new to VBA and tis is my 1st such project. this is what I have coded to select the value.

```
Sub automaticformfilling_ASDA()

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    'to make sure that the website is properly loaded

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.argos-pet-insurance.com/quoteAndBuy.do?e=e1s1&curPage=captureDetails&rakT=1510852044896.1391473424.994101.1731.881880349.846|tsid:9904"

        Do While .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop  
    End With

    Set Title = i.e.document.getElementById("yourDetailsPolicyHolderTitle")

    For i = 1 To Title.Options.Length
       If Title.Options(i).Text = "Mrs" Then
         Exit For
       End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the HTML of that section:

```
<select name="policyHolder.title" class="select-large" id="yourDetailsPolicyHolderTitle" data-di-field-id="policyHolderTitle">
   <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
   <option value="NWA_PET_T5">Dr</option>
   <option value="NWA_PET_T3">Miss</option>
   <option value="NWA_PET_T1">Mr</option>
   <option value="NWA_PET_T2">Mrs</option>
   <option value="NWA_PET_T4">Ms</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you want to select "Mrs" just use `Title.selectedindex = 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from SJR and also a typo I found in your code, if you replace your code with this then it should work:

```
Sub automaticformfilling_ASDA()

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    'to make sure that the website is properly loaded

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.argos-pet-insurance.com/quoteAndBuy.do?e=e1s1&curPage=captureDetails&rakT=1510852044896.1391473424.994101.1731.881880349.846|tsid:9904"

        Do While .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Set Title = ie.document.getElementById("yourDetailsPolicyHolderTitle")
    Title.selectedIndex = 4
End Sub
```

You entered i.e.document.getElementByID, where you should have ie.document.